# Python - Control Mouse input after focus is lost

Tags: python, background, terminal, minimized

I have a python code that uses the camera from the monitor and an IR pen to move the mouse.

However when i click on something else other than the terminal window, the computer is no longer in command of the terminal window, therefore the mouse doesn't move anymore on moving the IR pen.

I am looking for a code that would solve my problem.

Comment: What OS? What version of Python? What library are you using for monitoring? What is your code?

Comment: This seems like a very interesting thing you are trying, and I would love to help as best I can. But please provide more information as to the [FAQ] and [Ask]